# Ad mob banner ad suddenly stopped showing up since last week without making any change in the code

Tags: android, admob

In my android application, I have integrated AdMob and it was working fine. Just yesterday it suddenly stopped behaving properly.

I was using the following code.

**build.gradle :**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
```

**Android Manifest :**

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-9909994914600044~9516185764" />
<activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

**Layout :**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" />
```

**Activity :**

```
lateinit var adRequest: AdRequest
val android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(
        contentResolver,
        Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID
    )
    MobileAds.initialize(this@BannerAdActivity)
    adRequest = AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(android_id)
        .build()
 val adView = AdView(this)
    adView.adSize = AdSize.SMART_BANNER
    adView.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
    adView.loadAd(adRequest)
    adView.adListener = object : AdListener() {
        override fun onAdLoaded() {
        }
        override fun onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode: Int) {
        }
        override fun onAdOpened() {
        }
        override fun onAdClicked() {
        }
        override fun onAdLeftApplication() {
        }
        override fun onAdClosed() {
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions, please.

Comment: did you define paymant option AdMob ? and did you get any mail into registerd mail regarding to AdMob?

Answer (score 1):

Check your AdMob dashboard, you might have something wrong there

Answer (score 1):

Go to [Admob policy center](https://apps.admob.com/v2/policycenter) there might be a message there for you like "Ad serving has been limited"